# adding the values in a matrix based on the corresponding unique values of another matrix

Tags: matlab

```
e=[40 19 18 20 30 34 65 97 155 160];
```

If there is a minimum difference between two consecutive values (for e.g. (19,18), (30, 34) and (155,160)) then merge these values..

Similar values also...Whatever condition can be used to solve this..Kindly help to solve this..

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Look into `diff` as a possible use.

Comment: What do you mean by 'merge', 'similar values'?

Comment: merging the nearby values...the output will be like this c=[40 20 34 65 97 160]...conditions are diff between each element in an array will be minimum of 1 and maximum of 5..so minimum of 1 satisfies the values 19 18 20 and merges it as 20.. and maximum range helps to merge 30 34 and 155 160 values...kindly help me...

Comment: What would you want the result to be from merging e = 1:5:100001?
Following you example above, this would result in c = 100001.  It doesn't seem like a good definition of similar!!

Comment: This question is actually a turing test. There is a group of psychologists who test how much can be left out so humans are still capable of making sense from it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Iteratively,

```
e = [ 40 19 18 20 30 34 65 97 155 160];
current = e + 1; % init
prev = e;
while ~isequal( current, prev )
    prev = current;
    d = [ diff( prev ) < 5 true]; % always keep the last one
    current = prev( d );
end
```